# Find where android library is hosted

Tags: android, maven, gradle, jcenter

Since jcenter will be shut down in May, I'm wondering is there any automated way (gradle task or plugin) to iterate through all android libraries that I use and printing on which repository that library is hosted (jcenter, mavencentral, google).
I already tried with task like this, but it just printing library name (you can get library group or version also).

```
 task printConfigurations {
        doLast {
            project.configurations.each { config ->
                config.allDependencies.each { d ->
                    println(d.name)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove jCenter from your repositories configuration and rebuild the project.
Any now unresolved dependencies were apparently hosted on jCenter.

If it builds fine, it's fine.

Comment: I tried that. I removed jcenter and added mavecentral.  but my build failed because this dependency: org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824. So I still dont know how many other libraries are hosted on jcenter.  https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2021/02/04/migratingjcenter/
I can copy libraries names and search for it on jcenter, but it would be great to have some automated solution.

Comment: "but my build failed because this dependency" -- then that should be the only missing one, though note that (at least in my projects) you need that for both a Gradle plugin and an actual build, so you need to allow JCenter to download that for both the `buildscript` and the regular dependencies.